# Moving MdDialog Angular 2+

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, angular-material

How can i move MdDialog ("@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10")? Tried to use several drag and drop plugins (now on "ng2-drag-drop": "^2.6.0"). They allow me to move content of dialog, but not the dialog (popup) himself.

Open dialog:

```
public custom<DialogComponent>(component: any, config: MdDialogConfig) {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(component, config);
  }
```

Dialog template:

```
<div ngDraggable>
  <p> dialog content </p>
</div>
```

Dialog settings:

```
let config = new MdDialogConfig();
    config.disableClose = true;
    config.hasBackdrop = false;
    this.dialogService.custom<DialogComponent>(DialogComponent, config);
```